# Where are anonymous objects stored?

Tags: c, memory-layout

I expected them to be stored in the `text` segment, but a short investigations revealed they are not (I used `clang` compiler). So where then are they stored? The pointers to anonymous objects are defined globally (outside any scope) like this:

```
int *garr = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
void *grec = &(struct {float a; char b;}){0, 1};
```

I defined a pointer to a string literal and some constant variables globally:

```
char *gstr = "Global string";
const short global_const = 5;
static const unsigned static_global_const = 10;
```

Then I defined some variables for the `data` segment, also globally:

```
int data_x = 1;
char data_y = 2;
static float data_z = 3;
```

Then I checked the addresses of all of them and the content of the `gstr` pointer to get an idea where the `text` and the `data` segments are. The result was like this (lstr is a pointer to another string literal, but defined inside the `main` scope):

```
gstr == 0x4009a8
lstr == 0x400a18
&global_const == 0x400bb4
&static_global_const == 0x400bbc

&data_x == 0x601070
&data_y == 0x601074
Static: &data_z == 0x601078
```

Here what I see is that the first 4 addresses come from the `text` segment while the last 3 are from the `data` segment. I had expected anonymous objects to be near the first 4 addresses, but I saw this:

```
garr == 0x601040
grec == 0x601060
```

To me looks like they got stored into the `data` segment even though these objects are read-only literals. Why?

Comment: *Where* are those pointers defined?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Globally, outside any scopes. I do not think this matters since pointers to string literals defined both inside and outside the main scope pointed to neighbouring locations

Comment: `a short investigations revealed they are not (I used clang compiler)` What "short investigation"? How and what exactly did it revealed? `If investigation description is needed, I'll add it here` Yes! :) [MCVE]

Comment: *"I do not think this matters since pointers to string literals"* - Best not assume all literals are created equal.

Comment: It matters because compound literals have different storage duration depending on if they're defined at file scope or block scope.

Comment: Why not just look at the assembly output?

Comment: What makes you think the compound literals are read-only?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've always thought they are :) Looks like I can rewrite it

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well if they are read-write then the question does not make sense

Comment: @EricPostpischil I initially thought that if string literals are read-only then all literals are read only. Poor show

Comment: `Then I checked the addresses of all of them` How did you checked the addresses? Please post the full program. What compiler options did you use? I believe your compiler just optimizes the variables away. If you want to check the size of some section, check the size of that section with `size` or `readelf` and such, not with "printing addresses".

Comment: @KamilCuk just printed them out with %p and cast to void

Comment: @KamilCuk I was not intrested in the sizes of the sections, I only wanted to know where my variables and literals are thus guessing where approximately the entire sections are

Comment: @KamilCuk The addresses look quite ordered. Plus I used these very variables to get their addresses, so I doubt it could have deleted them before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers commonly put string literals in a read-only section because they are read-only. Similarly, initialized non-read-only data is put in a modifiable data section because that is what it is for.

A compound literal is not read-only unless it is defined with a const-qualified type, so a compiler is likely to put a non-const-qualified compound literal in a modifiable section.

(Of course, the C standard allows C implementations to arrange memory as they like, so a compiler is not obligated to use the same section for compound literals that it uses for other data.)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: I have modified the answer to be more generic. Way back when, I do not think we distinguished between read-only data and code. The fancy stuff came later.